# Microsoft Visual Studios Community "Add as Link" for VC++ Projects

Tags: visual-studio-2013

I have a VC++ project that I am working on in Visual Studios Community. Some of the code comes from shared files that are SVN maintained. Because I don't want to maintain duplicate copies of the shared files, I initially created Hard Links to the VC++ project directory. Then I found out that VS breaks Hard Links when you save because it creates a new file.... Ok, so I decided to link to the SVN files in my VS project, but I cannot do this?

I found [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9f4t9t92(v=vs.100).aspx), which shows how to add file links, but it only work for VS2010 or older. When I follow the directions and click on the down arrow on the **Add** button, I only have the options to **Add** or **Show Previous Versions**. Community is supposed to be the same as MSVS 2013 Pro. I cannot find any information regarding this feature for newer version of MSVS VC++ projects. Did they remove this feature? How can that be?

Comment: Try dragging the file you want to vs2013 with alt key pressed

Comment: @DeJaVo - This seems to work great! Thank you! I wonder why this isn't better documented or available as a common IDE function during the Add process? Please add this as an answer to the question so I can give you the proper credit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can drag the file you want with <kbd>alt</kbd> key pressed into vs2013.

It should help you achieve the required behavior.